# Grails 2.0 with Java 7 - ready for production?

Tags: grails, java, java-7

Any reasons that I should or should not use Oracle JRE 7 in production?

Actually I am not planning on doing this since I am getting an error javac: target release 1.6 conflicts with default source release 1.7

It is a bug (http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8393) but the fix does not seem to work.

Comment: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8393 fix is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle JRE 7 should be good to go - there aren't any known showstopper issues.

Of course, you should test thoroughly before you deploy, but you do that already for any deployment, right? :-)

Comment: lol ... yes full regression test :)

Comment: you have any experience with grails and java 7?

Comment: I'm running Java 7 at the moment in production. No problems so far. I'm not using Grails but don't see why Grails should cause any additional issues (it's pure Java, right?)

Comment: @mikera no, the Grails framework is written in a mixture of Java and Groovy and Grails apps can also include code in both languages